# How to kill & restart dock using terminal

Tags: mac, operating-systems

I used to have the command to kill the dock & restart it. Can I have it again?

Comment: Did you research this question, perhaps doing a Google search?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does not show the minimum effort of self resolution or research before asking.

Answer (score 0):

`killall Dock` Should do the trick.

Comment: Does this restart it as well?